# How to loop battle phase games c#

Tags: c#, function, loops, class

I'm new to c# and don't completely understand for loops. I am working on a text-based wizard game recommended by brackeys on youtube. At the start of the game, you are asked to chose your spell, let's say "bugs(costs  13mana, deals 2dmg)" you have 3 spell slots and 10hp. When it's time to attack calculations are done etc to reduce the enemy's(frog(10hp)) hp. So after the frog attacks, I want to start over the battle(loop) for me to attack again and the frog to attack again. And the game will be over when either I or the enemy has 0hp. I know for sure I'm coding right but the way I'm using classes and functions are too much and I bet there are simpler ways to do it but I just don't know.

I'm not sure this project is too big for a beginner but yea lol. I was thinking of using a for loop but I don't completely understand how it works.
When I run it only loops the part that asked which spell you want to use and minuses your mana and spell slots. It only loops that and doest attack Also, I'm kinda new to this site so I don't know the proper way of laying out my work.

```
class Wizard
    {
        //Wiz Profile
        public string name;
        public int  myHp = 10;
        public int myMana = 20;
        public string userAttack;
        public string favoriteSpell;
        private int spellSlots;
        private float xp;
        public static int Count;
        /////////////////////////

        //Spells Profile
        public int bugsDmg = 2;
        public int bugsMana = 13;
        public int rottingFodderDmg = 3;
        public int rottingFodderMana = 10;
        public int owlDmg = 5;
        public int owlMana = 10;
        //////////////////////////////////////////

        //Enemies Profile
        public int frogHp = 10;

       
             //Here is where I attempted to make the loop
        public void Gameover()
        {
            while(myHp > 0){
                Gameactive();
            }
        }       
                //I don't use this I just got this in brackets tutorial I will use it when
                  getting user name and spell not really sure of to use functions taking stuff 
                    in the brackets
         public Wizard(string _name, string _favoriteSpell)
        {
            name = _name;
            favoriteSpell =  _favoriteSpell;
            spellSlots = 3;
            xp = 0f;
            
            Count++;
        }
        
          //This is done after the spell calculation is done
        public void Battle()
        {
           userAttack = Console.ReadLine();
           
            if((userAttack == "Bugs") || (userAttack == "bugs"))
            {
                CastSpell();
                frogHp =frogHp - bugsDmg;
                Console.WriteLine("You casted " + userAttack + ". Dealth " + bugsDmg + " 
                 damage!");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Frog hp: " + frogHp +"hp" +   " Your hp: " + myHp + "hp  Your 
                  mana: " + myMana + "mana");
                Console.WriteLine("Spell Slots: " + spellSlots + " slots left");
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
            if( (userAttack == " Rotting Fodder") || (userAttack == "rottingfodder") || 
               (userAttack == "rotting fodder"))
            {
                CastSpell();
                frogHp =frogHp - rottingFodderDmg;
                Console.WriteLine("You casted " + userAttack + ". Dealth " + rottingFodderDmg + 
                 " damage!");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Frog hp: " + frogHp +"hp" +   " Your hp: " + myHp + "hp  Your
                mana: " + myMana + "mana");
                Console.WriteLine("Spell Slots: " + spellSlots + " slots left");
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);

            }

        }

           //This is called when an enemy(the frog) attacks
        public void Enemyattack()
        {
            myHp = myHp - rottingFodderDmg;
            Console.WriteLine("You got hit with rotting fodder");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            Console.WriteLine("Dealth" +  rottingFodderDmg + " damage!");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Frog hp: " + frogHp +"hp     Your hp: " + myHp + "hp     Your  
             mana: " + myMana + "mana");
            Console.WriteLine("Spell Slots: " + spellSlots + " slots left");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
        }

          //This is the calculation that happens when a player chooses a spell
        public void CastSpell(){
            if((userAttack == "Bugs") || (userAttack == "bugs"))
            {
                myMana = myMana - bugsMana;
                spellSlots--;
                Console.WriteLine("-15 mana,    -1 Spell Slot");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
              if( (userAttack == " Rotting Fodder") || (userAttack == "rottingfodder") ||   
                (userAttack == "rotting fodder"))
            {
                myMana = myMana - rottingFodderMana;
                spellSlots--;
                Console.WriteLine("-15 mana,    -1 Spell Slot");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                
            }
            Gameover();
        }

        public void Meditate(){
            Console.WriteLine(name + " meditates to regain spell slots.");
            spellSlots = 2;
        }
         
           ////////////////I assumed by making this into a func. I will be able to loop the part
            ///that takes user input then to attack again
        public void Gameactive()
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Select Your Spell to attack: \nBugs(costs 15 mana)   Rotting 

            Fodder(costs 4 mana)");

            
            Battle();

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Standby Phase...");
            Thread.Sleep(2);
            Console.WriteLine("Frog is attacking...");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            Enemyattack();
            }
           
        
            
    }

   
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "WizardMadness";
            //Making a new wizard
            string userName;
            string userGender;
            string userFavoriteSpell;

            Wizard player1 = new Wizard(/*userName*/"Aaron", "Bugs" /*userFavoriteSpell*/);

          
            Console.WriteLine(Wizard.Count + " wizard created.");

          
            Console.WriteLine("Time to go into battle");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("You ran into a Frog!");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Frog hp: 10hp    Your hp: 10hp   Your mana: 20mana\nSpell Slots: 
            3 slots available");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            player1.Gameactive();
```

Comment: You use `while` loops, so I assume you understand how they work: a `while` loop checks the condition; if true then the loop body is entered; if the end of the body is reached or a `continue` is reached then the condition is checked again, and so on.  You get `while` loops, right?

Comment: A `for` loop is just a shorter way of writing a `while` loop.  `for(INIT; CONDITION; INC) BODY` is just a short way of writing `{ INIT; while (CONDITION) { BODY; INC } }`  So if you understand `while` loops, `for` loops are very straightforward. You just mentally translate the `for` into the equivalent `while`. Remember, you can **always** write a `for` loop as a `while` loop if you prefer. `for` loops are just a convenience.

Comment: (There is one small subtlety and that is in a `for`, a `continue` goes to the `INC`.)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to programming! There are a few things you can do to up your code and clean it up a little.

1. Use .ToLower() for your if statements
2. Consider using a DO WHILE loop for your game state
3. You can NEST your if statements
   if
   {
   if
   {
   }
   else if
   {
   }
   else
   {
   }
   }
4. Using libraries will clean up your code, separating your methods and functions can really help you trouble shoot and debug as well. Making your "main" 30 lines instead of 300
5. Learn what an if statement actually does. Think of it like this, your program runs top to bottom, so once it goes through that statement it is done, unless there is a loop to reprompt and make it go through it again, but once that statement is cleared, it will not be seen again ( you can nest your if statements in your do while loops)
   Hope this helps! Not complete answers, but programming is about logic, and once you figure it out it will click, good luck!